# Burger eating contest

Tags: prepositions

> Contest of burger eating
>
> Burger eating  contest

Is there any difference between two phrases . I mean does “of” change meaning in this phrase. I thought there is no difference but “ of” realy confuses me.

Comment: No native speaker would say "contest of burger eating." On the other hand "burger-eating contest" (with the hyphen) is perfectly correct and idiomatic. Where did you see the former?

Comment: I did not see it anywhere. I just wonder if it is grammatical or not, or it is grammatical but unnatural.

Comment: It is gramamtical but unnatural. I'm not sure why: _contest_ doesn't normally take an "of" complement.

Answer (score 1):

No native speaker would say "contest of burger eating." On the other hand "burger-eating contest" (with the hyphen) is perfectly correct and idiomatic.

*Contest* doesn't normally take an "of" complement. 
This phenomenon can be generalized, it's not specific to "contest".

"voting machine", not "machine of voting"
"cup holder", not "holder of cups"
"desk lamp", not "lamp of the desk"
"racing car", not "car of racing"
"hiking boots", not "boots of hiking"

There are probably thousands of examples.